# Datastructure like Treemap with duplicate keys and ceilingkey in Java

Tags: guava, treemap, multimap, ceil

UPDATE

```
Multimap<Double, PowerHost> createHostListofAvailableMIPS()
{
        List<PowerHost> tempList = hosts;
        Multimap<Double, PowerHost> listOfAvailableMIPS = TreeMultimap.create(Ordering.natural(), Ordering.arbitrary());

        for (PowerHost p : tempList)
        {
            //build tree
            listOfAvailableMIPS.put(p.getAvailableMips(), p);
        }
        return listOfAvailableMIPS;
}


PowerHost getHost (Vm vm)
    {
        this.reqdMIPS = vm.getMips();
        Multimap<Double, PowerHost> sortedPHs = createHostListofAvailableMIPS();
        PowerHost selectedHost = null;                  
        //gets mips that are >= reqdMIPS ie best matches
        NavigableSet<Double> ns =  (NavigableSet<Double>) sortedPHs.keySet();
        Double x = ns.ceiling(reqdMIPS);

//other codes follow

}
```

I noticed there is a . in the statement that is

```
Treemap.<Double, PowerHost>create().keySet().ceiling(K)
```

This I believe could also work, would try this when I get home. However using the code above:

```
NavigableSet<Double> ns = (NavigableSet<Double>) sortedPHs.keySet()
```

returns only one item rather than a Set of Doubles

Is there any in built structure in java that is a combination of feature sets from Treemap + multimap?

What I want is basically a Treemap that can support multiple/duplicate keys. I know a multimap (from guava) can do that but I cannot use the ceilingkey(K) on Multimap.

My initial plan was to use a TreeMultimap and then use keyset().ceiling(k)
but eclipse keeps rejecting the statements:

```
Multimap <Double, someObject> myMM= TreeMultimap.create();
```

Complains about "Bound mismatch", saying someObject is not a valid substitute for

keyset().ceiling(k) complains that method ceiling is undefined in Set.

Helps / Suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: 1) It should be `keySet().ceiling(k)` (note the upper case 'S'). 2) I cannot reproduce your issue because `TreeMultimap.<Double, Comparable>create().keySet().ceiling(0.0);` compiles fine for me. Can you provide actual code that reproduces the problem you're having?

Answer (score 2):

To solve the first problem, you'll need to use [`MultimapBuilder`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MultimapBuilder.html) instead of `TreeMultimap`. `TreeMultimap` requires that both keys and values be `Comparable`. With `MultimapBuilder`, you can mix `Comparable` keys with non-`Comparable` values and still get a sorted `keySet`.

```
ListMultimap<Double, SomeObject> myMM =
    MultimapBuilder.treeKeys().arrayListValues().build();
```

To solve the second problem, you'll need to cast the returned `keySet` to a `SortedSet`. (This is [documented as safe when using `MultimapBuilder.treeKeys`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MultimapBuilder.html#treeKeys()).) That's still not enough to get you `ceiling`, though, as that's available only on `NavigableMap` :( You'll have to use something like `getFirst(tailSet(k), null)`.